# WinRM - Basic Authentication Issue - Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration

Tags: windows-10, winrm

I am not exactly sure what is my issue, I think I have everything set correctly.  I am trying to test WinRM with simple basic authentication using HTTP (unencrypted) to a Windows 10 machine that has HyperV enabled.  This HyperV server is just a system located in my home lab.  There is no domain controller/active directory in my setup.

I followed online tutorials to 1) enable basic authentication on both service and client, 2) set allow unencrypted to true and 3) set trusted hosts.

Below is my configuration on the server end on 192.168.98.* subnet.

```
PS WSMan:\localhost\Client> winrm get winrm/config/service/auth
Auth
    Basic = true
    Kerberos = true
    Negotiate = true
    Certificate = false
    CredSSP = false
    CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed

PS WSMan:\localhost\Client> winrm get winrm/config/client
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = true
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = 192.168.98.86,192.168.20.*
```

I verified that my listener on 5985 is enabled.

However, when I try to execute a sample command from a client located on 192.168.20.* subnet, I got the following:

```
PS C:\Users\dchu> winrm identify -r:http://192.168.98.86:5985 -auth:basic -u:beyonddc -p:fooPassword -encoding:utf-8
WSManFault
    Message = The WinRM client cannot process the request. Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again.

Error number:  -2144108322 0x803380DE
The WinRM client cannot process the request. Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again.
PS C:\Users\dchu>
```

Much appreciated if someone can shed me some light.  Thanks!!!

Comment: `AllowUnencrypted` is enabled on the client side too? Because you showed us the server-side configuration only

Comment: I didn't enable WinRM on the client machine.  Is there a way to set "AllowUnencrypted" on the client machine without enabling WinRM service?